# php paypal integration

Tags: php

I want to return the invoice generated after a PayPal payment on my website. How do I get the PayPal invoice generated after this payment is made?

Comment: You're missing something there... And you should really pay more attention to your spelling, the text is nearly illegible. Anyways, I guess that what you want is found in PayPal developer documentation either under the term "PDT" (Payment Data Transfer) or "IPN" (Instant Payment Notification).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get every information from PayPal using [PayPal API](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/howto_api_reference).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not 100% clear. PayPal already sends an invoice (you can customize this from your PayPal account) upon payment completion.
What you can do on your side is to handle payment confirmation using PDT or IPN. I would recommend the second one since is more reliable. Once you get the payment confirmation through IPN you can send to customer your own generated invoice based on the order data.
If you are interested to easily integrate your custom shopping cart with PayPal please read [this article](http://www.softarea51.com/blog/how-to-integrate-your-custom-shopping-cart-with-paypal-website-payments-standard-using-php/).